# MySql get highest count per parent ID

Tags: mysql

```
ID    item_ID    parent_ID   count
================================
1      11          2          5
2      12          2          6
3      13          3          2
4      14          3          3
5      15          2          7
6      16          1          3
```

`SELECT * FROM relations ORDER BY count DESC`

The row that should be returns are 2,4 and 6 because they have the highest count for their `parent_ID`

how do i change the query to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want the higehst one or every data that is greater than x?

Comment: No, i want the highest `count` for each `parent_ID`

Answer (score 1):

The inner select gets the highest count for each `parent_ID`. If you join against that, it filters out the relevant records

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
join
(
    select parent_ID, max(count) as mcount
    from your_table
    group by parent_ID
) t2 on t1.parent_ID = t2.parent_ID
    and t1.count = t2.mcount
```